# how to cancel or delete previous purchase in non auto- renewal in-purchase queue which are cenceled in sendbox mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase

In my application I am using auto-renewal in app purchase, but I am facing a problem in case of canceling the purchase. If I cancel the purchase and repurchase it then it is showing the previous canceled purchase completion alert in which it is asking for the password of my sandbox testing id, which is in its `SKPaymentQueue`. I want to remove that canceled purchase from the queue before the new purchase starts. I tried the remove observation method but its not working in my case. If any one knows the solution please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also having same problem. How to remove previous cancelled transactions. Someone please guide.

Comment: What do you mean by "cancel the purchase". Do you mean you hit "cancel" when the purchase process prompts you for the password? What is the state of the SKPaymentTransaction?

Comment: Exactly hit the cancel button when ask for payment, and i stopped the application, next time when i launch the app i try for purchase again, first i got the state SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed, then current purchase process begins.

Comment: Actually i want to remove the dialog that request my password automatically for even previous failed transaction

Comment: i want to cancel or delete the previous failed of cancel purchase that is store in [SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by checking my code with Apple's sample code of IAP i found on apple's discussion forum.  It is implemented by following apple's best practices of adding and removing transaction observers. Please refer code in this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc1991/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014726